# Как подключить стили css к тегу <a>

Tags: html, css

При создании Spring Boot приложения столкнулся с проблемой подключения css к html. Перепробовал все способы подключения, но ничего не помогает.

HTML head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Last Day - Catalog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
```

```css
a {
  border: 2px black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ЭТОТ ДЕНЬ В ИСТОРИИ" class="catalog button" onclick="window.location.href='history'">
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/history">Этот день в истории</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/NHL">NHL</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/horoscope">Гороскоп</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/NASA">Picture of the Day (NASA)</a>
```

Причём стили для input type button подключились

Comment: Стили применились, рамок не видно, потому что не задан тип (например `border: 2px solid black;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padding` и ещё некоторые правила, не применяются к элементам с `display: inline`, а `<a>` по дефолту именно такой.
Допишите `display: inline-block`.

Так же не указан стиль бордера [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style), в `border` он обычно указывается между размером и цветом:

```
border: width style color;
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ЭТОТ ДЕНЬ В ИСТОРИИ" class="catalog button" onclick="window.location.href='history'">
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/history">Этот день в истории</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/NHL">NHL</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/horoscope">Гороскоп</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/catalog/NASA">Picture of the Day (NASA)</a>
```